# How do I stop WordPress from redirecting certain links automatically on homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display filtered results on the homepage of a WooCommerce shop by editing the URL.

I have a filtering option by tag, category and price range.

The URL for filtering by tag would look like this:

```
sitename.com/shop/?product_tag=tag1
```

And that redirects automatically to

```
sitename.com shop/product-tag/tag1/
```

Which I don't want because I want to add other filtering options, for example, like this:

```
sitename.com/shop/?product_tag=tag1&product_cat=category1
```

If I put this filter on a different page than the /shop/, it doesn't redirect and display the results there, on the page.

How can I disable this annoying WP redirect?

I tried this following one but didn't work:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
  add_rewrite_rule('^shop/?$', 'index.php?page_id={your_page_id for this page}', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

or use the following code

```
function redirect_prevent()
{
add_action('redirect_canonical','__return_false');
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_prevent',1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You rewrite rule is quite broad and will most likely generate a lot of conflicts

```
add_action('init', 'mqx_rewrite_tags');
function mqx_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%tagname%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'mqx_rewrite_rules');
function mqx_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^shop/(.+)/?$','index.php?page_id=12646&tagname=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

##### ! important

Remember to flush the rewrite rules; you can do it by going to Settings -> Permalinks and clicking on save button.